# AppFuse: mvn jetty:run cannot find symbol

Tags: java, maven, appfuse

I'm trying to do some basic application in AppFuse (multi-modular) and I'm stuck with this error. I have an `DailyRecord` entity, `DailyRecordDao` interface, `DailyRecordDaoHibernate` class, and `DRManagerImpl` class.

There are three methods in `DailyRecordDao`:

```java
package com.diary.dao;

import java.sql.Date;
import java.util.List;

import org.appfuse.dao.GenericDao;

import com.diary.model.DailyRecord;

public interface DailyRecordDao extends GenericDao<DailyRecord, Long> {

    public List<DailyRecord> getDailyRecordsFrom(Date date, Long memberID);

    public DailyRecord getTodayDailyRecord(Long memberID);

    public DailyRecord getDailyRecord(Long memberID);
}
```

here is the `DailyRecordDaoHibernate` which implements this interface

```java
package com.diary.dao;

import java.sql.Date;
import java.util.Calendar;
import java.util.List;

import org.apache.logging.log4j.LogManager;
import org.apache.logging.log4j.Logger;
import org.appfuse.dao.hibernate.GenericDaoHibernate;
import org.hibernate.criterion.Restrictions;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Repository;

import com.diary.model.DailyRecord;

@Repository("dailyRecordDao")
public class DailyRecordDaoHibernate extends GenericDaoHibernate<DailyRecord, Long>
        implements DailyRecordDao {

    public DailyRecordDaoHibernate() {
        super(DailyRecord.class);
    }

    @Override
    public List<DailyRecord> getDailyRecordsFrom(Date date, Long memberID) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        return null;   //this isn't importat right now
    }

    @Override
    public DailyRecord getTodayDailyRecord(Long memberID) {

        return null;   //again not important, but this method works well when called in DRManagerImpl
    }

    @Override
    public DailyRecord getDailyRecord(Long memberID) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        return null;    //this method causes the problem
    }

}
```

And here is the manager:

```java
package com.diary.service;

import java.sql.Date;
import java.util.List;

import org.appfuse.service.impl.GenericManagerImpl;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Service;

import com.diary.dao.DailyRecordDao;
import com.diary.model.DailyRecord;


@Service("drm")
public class DRManagerImpl extends GenericManagerImpl<DailyRecord, Long> implements
        DRManager {

    private DailyRecordDao drDao;

    @Autowired
    public DRManagerImpl(DailyRecordDao dailyRecordDao) {
        this.drDao = dailyRecordDao;
    }

    @Override
    public List<DailyRecord> getAll() {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        return drDao.getAll();
    }

    @Override
    public List<DailyRecord> getDailyRecordsFrom(Date date, Long memberID) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        return drDao.getDailyRecordsFrom(date, memberID);
    }

    @Override
    public DailyRecord getTodayDailyRecord(Long memberID) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
//      return drDao.getTodayDailyRecord(memberID);   this works
        return drDao.getDailyRecord(memberID);       //this will cause the error
    }

}
```

When I try to run the application with `mvn jetty:run` I get this error

```
[ERROR] COMPILATION ERROR :
[INFO] --------------------------------------
[ERROR] .../web/src/main/java/com/diary/service/DRManagerImpl.java[46,29] cannot find symbol
  symbol:    method getDailyRecord(java.lang.Long)
  location:  variable drDao of type com.diary.dao.DailyRecordDao
```

But if uncomment the `getTodayDailyRecord()` in manager and comment the `getDailyRecord()` method, everythig works. I think it has something to do with dependecies, but I'm really not sure since this is really confusing for me. I already tried `mvn clean compile` on web and core directories, deleting the `target` folders in those directories and then recompile it again but still, no luck. I will appreciate any help.

Answer (score 0):

Ok, so I managed to get it working. Without changing *anything*, I had written JUnit test which basicaly tests if `dailyRecordDao.getDailyRecord()` returns `null`. The test passed and everything went fine magically. I'm not sure whether I'm happy or just more confused.

Comment: You have to do "mvn install" on your core project in order for your web project to pick it up.

Comment: Ah, I thought I only need to do it at the begging of the project, thank you very very much!